# How do I get the name of a tag in TinyXML?

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

For example:

test.xml

```
<fruit taste="good">whatever</fruit>
```

How can I get the name-string of the tag "fruit" (which would be "fruit" of course) using TinyXML?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [TiXmlElement::Value()](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html#d44dfe927d49a74dd78b72b7514417ad)

The Value function returns different things based on the type.

```
    Document:   filename of the xml file
    Element:    name of the element
    Comment:    the comment text
    Unknown:    the tag contents
    Text:       the text string
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that if you use the STL, you can also use [TiXmlNode::ValueStr()](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html#74bda074919e4a5e08d700204793f898) which returns `const std:string&` instead of `const char *`.  It's more efficient too.